# Can I have two different theme for two different language?

Tags: theme-development, themes, theme-options, multi-language, language

I have to develop a multilanguage website using WordPress (Italian and English) and I want to know if I can have a theme for the Italian version and a differen theme for the English version.

Can I do this thing?

Tnx

Andrea

Answer (score 1):

A [WordPress Multi-site](http://codex.wordpress.org/Create_A_Network) can handle multiple languages with individual themes and plugins activ.

It's like having multiple sites, one for every language, within one Installation. Every Site can have it's own design, set of activ plugins and users.

Read troth Method No. 5 on this Page for Details and Plugins that can help:
http://codex.wordpress.org/Multilingual_WordPress